# How to Intent simple activity class to Fragment?

Tags: android

I have two java files one extends simple Activity MainActivity.java and second extends fragment sample.java when i try to intent in MainActivity to second it shows error .ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

public class LoginPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
private Button btn;
private EditText user;
private EditText pass;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
//JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private Button btn1;

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";
private static final String TAG_LOGIN = "login";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginmailid);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginpwd);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.btnreg:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
            break;
    }

}
```

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginPage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
         try {
             //Building Parameters


             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "apps"));

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
             final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
             System.out.println("MSG : " + msg);

             runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
             {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            });
             return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

             //http://gujjumatch.com/login?version=apps&email=GM847903@param.in&password=123456
             //JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("login");

            //System.out.println(arr.toString());
            //JSONObject arr1  = new JSONObject(json);
            //String ss=arr1.getString("status");
            //System.out.println(ss);
            //System.out.println(arr1.getString("status"));
             //String date = jObj.getString("status");
            // json success tag
            // success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
         if(file_url.equals("success")) {

                // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                 Intent i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, HomeFragment.class);

                 startActivity(i);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }else{
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
}}
```

}

Comment: source code please. How you're calling fragment from activity using intent?

Comment: It obvious because your second java class is `Fragment` not a `Activity` which never call using `Intent`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta is there any solution ?help me i edit my code now i just want to intent to fragment class

Comment: do u know how to open fragmantin android

Comment: have a look this to open fragment in android http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

Comment: @Eddie You can change it to `Activity` or use `FragmentTransaction` for call a `Fragment`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta i cant change it to activity so describe more about Fragement transaction

Comment: @Eddie Refer these links http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm , http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html

Comment: I had same problem try this link it will give help  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a fragment. It is noto an activity. Put it into an activity and try again

Comment: i am using navigation drawer its not possible to make it in activity.

Comment: So use a FrameLayout and replace the fragment when you need it